# Using LiquidXML with noNamespaceSchemaLocation

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, liquid-xml

When I generate my C# code I get a namespace with 'AA' when noNamespaceSchemaLocation is defined?

The docs talk about adding a NamespaceAlias to the Default context here:
http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Reference/XmlDataBinding/source/HowTo/ChangeNamespaceAliases.htm

But there is no mention of noNamespaceSchemaLocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to create XML that looks a bit like this

```
<RootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.foo.com/schemaDirectory/bar.xsd" ...>
```

But your getting something that looks like this

```
<RootElement xmlns:AA="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" AA:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.foo.com/schemaDirectory/bar.xsd" ...>
```

In order to get the namespace alias 'xsi' instead of 'AA' (or similar)  you need to define the namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', this can be done like this:-

```
LiquidTechnologies.Runtime.Net40.XmlSerializationContext.Default.NamespaceAliases.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Comment: Yes that's correct. I must have accidentally deleted the line that adds 'xsi'. Thanks.